# How to call different function code based on parameters(Pluggable) in Golang

Tags: go

I would like to implement a project that `enables several different features based on different startup parameters or configuration files`, **a pluggable feature set**. The desired effect is that *main.go* can call the *run function* in `cmd/<feature>/<feature>.go` according to the parameters

```
├── cmd
│   ├── feature1
│   │   └── feature1.go
│   └── feature2
│       └── feature2.go
├── pkg
│   ├── feature1
│   │   └── feature1.go
│   └── feature2
│       └── feature2.go
└── main.go
```

Projects are `complex` and need to be `extended`

Is there a `design pattern` or an `existing project` that can be learned, if there is hope you can give advice

I really appreciate any help with this.

Comment: switch statement

Comment: @ArtūrsLataks I don't think this is a scalable way, this should be considered as a last resort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're two things that should be discussed here.

1. Project structure
2. Extendability and maintainability

If you want to build a single application, I would recommend you to have one module in the `cmd` directory and all features in the `pkg` directory (one cmd dir/file per application):

```
├── cmd
│   └── main.go
└── pkg
    ├── features
    │   ├── feature1.go
    │   ├── feature2.go
    │   └── feature3.go
    └── service
        └── service.go
```

If the feature set should be extendable, you probably will need an interface, that will be implemented by all features, for example:

```golang
type Feature interface {
    Run(context.Context) error
}
```

Also, you will have a service that should be constructed with provided features:

```golang
// pkg/service/service.go

type Service interface {
    Run(context.Context) error
}

// service is the Service implementation
type service struct {
    features []Feature
}

// Run runs the service. The service runs the features.
func (s *service) Run (ctx context.Context) error {
    for _, f := range s.features {
        err := f.Run(ctx)
        // check the error
    }
    // the rest of your code 
}
```

It should be easy to create a service with an arbitrary set of features. The simplest way is to pass a slice of features to the service constructor function:

```golang
func NewService(features []Feature) Service {
    return &service{features: features}
}
```

A more elegant way to pass your features to the service constructor is to use [functional options pattern](https://www.sohamkamani.com/golang/options-pattern/).

Comment: Thank you for your help. It is not a simple project to build, so the above project structure does not apply. The interface extensibility is very suitable, but how do I set up and enable certain features. For example, flag reads a `list of feature strings`, but how does this map to the corresponding feature?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. The answer to this question does not fit in a comment. I suppose you should create a new question for that.